# C language receive struct in another function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, send

when I try to read the value of `t[1].name` inside `equalname` function,  it won't work. How can I send that value over to another function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct test {
    char name[100];
    char num[100];
};

int equalname(struct test *t, char string[100]) {
    int i;
    t = malloc(sizeof(struct test)*100);
    printf("t[1].name == %s\n", t[1].name); //prints garbage(t[1].name != name)
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) //also, is this even right?
    {
        if (t[i].name == string) //should I use 2 for's and set t[i].name[j] == string[j]?
        {
            printf("t[i].name == name!");
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("WRONG");
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct test *t;
    t = malloc(sizeof(struct test)*100);
    char name[100];
    printf("Name:\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    strcpy(t[1].name, name);
    printf("t[1].name == %s\n", t[1].name); //this works (t[1].name == name)
    equalname(t[1].name, name);
}
```

Comment: This code should be generating warnings for not passing the correct type.

Comment: `strcpy(t[1].name, name);` -- `1` or did you mean `0`? As it sits you invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to access the uninitialized values with `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)` and `if (t[i].name == string)` -- there is nothing in `t[0], t[2], ...` To avoid the undefined behavior, use `calloc (100, sizeof *t)` to allocate and set all bytes zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is you are on the right track -- the bad news is there are a couple of rails missing from your track...

To begin, when you allocate memory with `malloc`, the block of memory is reserved, but all bytes within the block remain *uninitialized*. Attempting to access anything within an uninitialized memory location is *Undefined Behavior* -- the operation of your code is no longer defined from that point forward -- it could appear to work or SegFault or anything in between.

You have two choices, (1) either loop through each struct and explicitly initialize the values, or (2) use `calloc` that will allocate and initialize all bytes to zero, e.g.

```
#define MAXN 100    /* if you need a constrant #define 1 (or more) */

struct test {
    char name[MAXN];
    char num[MAXN];
};
...    

int main() {

    int index;
    struct test *t;
    char name[MAXN] = "";
    t = calloc(MAXN, sizeof *t);    /* use calloc, or initialize values */

    if (t == NULL) {                /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("calloc-t");
        return 1;
    }
```

Do not allocate `t` again in `equalname`. While that does not overwrite your original address due to C using pass by value, and `t` being a copy of `t` from main -- it also does nothing for you accept create another uninitialized block of memory. Just pass `t` from `main` and use it, e.g.

```
int equalname (struct test *t, char *string) 
{
    int i;

    printf("t[1].name == %s\n", t[1].name);

    for (i = 0; i < MAXN; i++)
    {   /* you must use strcmp to compare strings, not == */
        if (strcmp (t[i].name, string) == 0)
        {
            printf ("t[i].name == name!\n");
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("WRONG");
    return -1;
}
```

Next, you cannot compare strings with `==`. You either have to loop over each character and compare -- or just use `strcmp` (that's what it was written to do), e.g.

```
        if (strcmp (t[i].name, string) == 0)
        {
            printf ("t[i].name == name!\n");
            return i;
            break;  /* break does nothing here */
        }
```

Next, you must ***validate*** every allocation and every user input -- otherwise you are inviting *Undefined Behavior*. If you fail to validate allocations and fail to validate input -- you can have no confidence you are actually processing valid data in valid memory within your code.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXN 100    /* if you need a constrant #define 1 (or more) */

struct test {
    char name[MAXN];
    char num[MAXN];
};

int equalname (struct test *t, char *string) 
{
    int i;

    printf("t[1].name == %s\n", t[1].name);

    for (i = 0; i < MAXN; i++)
    {   /* you must use strcmp to compare strings, not == */
        if (strcmp (t[i].name, string) == 0)
        {
            printf ("t[i].name == name!\n");
            return i;
            break;
        }
    }

    printf("WRONG");
    return -1;       /* on error return a value that cannot be a valid index */
}

int main() {

    int index;
    struct test *t;
    char name[MAXN] = "";
    t = calloc(MAXN, sizeof *t);    /* use calloc, or initialize values */

    if (t == NULL) {                /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("calloc-t");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("Name: ");
    if (scanf ("%s", name) != 1) {  /* validate ALL user input */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input - name.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy (t[1].name, name);

    printf ("t[1].name == %s\n", t[1].name);
    index = equalname (t, name);    /* save the return! */

    if (index == -1) {  /* validate the operation of your function */
        fprintf (stderr, "string '%s' not found.\n", name);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("string found at index '%d'.\n", index);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_find_str
Name: Alfred
t[1].name == Alfred
t[1].name == Alfred
t[i].name == name!
string found at index '1'.
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Nice analogy. Last time I looked, couple missing rails = no track at all. :)

Comment: Sure, glad to help. The best advice I can give learning C is simply to slow down... There is a lot to learn. There is no guessing in C. Read the man page for every function you use, pay attention to the return type, the parameter types, and the section marked RETURN. It will tell you exactly what to expect as a return from the function and whether `errno` is set so you can output the error text with `perror` and whether you can use a call to `ferror` to check for the error condition. Validate everything by checking the return and handling the error. There is a lot to learn `:)`